# Magten 1.9 - Onestepcheckout - Success.phtml not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, third-party-module, local.xml, onestepcheckout

Greetings stackoverflow.

I'm helping a friend out with a Magento store. They have recently installed the [OneStepCheckout](https://www.onestepcheckout.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwlv_XBRDrARIsAH-iRJTBxs57iSzdk6Ji6OnK4MSGJDUkNzM-30KsmPidgJ7uo8uZQbZuUPcaAr3hEALw_wcB) module. Regarding them, after the installation the successpage seems not to work. I have checked in base folder and package folders. There is a success.phtml present in all folders. I have not worked with onestepcheckout before. I can not find a setting in the backend or code, that controls the success page redirect.

The checkout url seems to be wrong as it append and extra "/" - eg. https://www.myshop.dk/onestepcheckout//  <---- notice "//".

Here is my local.xml - https://gist.github.com/andreastherkildsen/7bf10839639b4ff41a12555053fa2e59

Here is onestepcheckout.xml - 
https://gist.github.com/andreastherkildsen/00a32dc287a4095be6836f8514f7e841

Can anybody give me a go on what could be missing?

The successpage is blank as shown on the image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wether this is a legit answer, but i got it to work in the following way.

Override and implementation of following code in: 
1. **app/code/local/Idev/OneStepCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
  public function successAction() 
  {
    // $this->loadLayout();
    // $this->renderLayout();
    $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
    $update->addHandle('default');
    $this->addActionLayoutHandles();
    $update->addHandle('custom_checkout_success');
    $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
    $this->generateLayoutXml();
    $this->generateLayoutBlocks();
    $this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

2. Update and implementation in [local.xml](https://gist.github.com/andreastherkildsen/1c0dabd908d1930dd5b2ebe43f68892c)
3. Here is the result: 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not hack it like that. Please contact module support, there is a ticket submit form and support email address on the module providers website.

Comment: I agree to some degree - Of course, I have contacted the module developer - but this serves fine as a hotfix in the first place, until their support comes back. 

I would not call it "hacking" since there have been made local and correct overrides on the module - the only thing their successAction does is to render a layout. The layout handler that i have added just tells it very specific what handler and template file that it should render/return. 

Hence it is not anything that takes care of payments or other critical information its not that "bad" of an override. :)